# #include<utility> in dev c++ header file

Tags: c++, include, header-files, dev-c++, std-pair

i am trying to create a header file in c++ with the following code

```
#ifndef dictionary_h
#define dictionary_h
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
template <class K,class E>
class dictionary
{
    virtual bool empty() const=0;
    virtual int size() const=0;
    virtual pair<const K,E>* find(const K&) const=0;
    virtual void insert(const pair<const K,E> &)=0;
    virtual void erase(const K&)=0;
};

#endif
```

but when i hit **F9** to compile it says,

```
[Error] utility: No such file or directory
```

what is the correct procedure for creating a header file for dev c++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev C++ associates .h files with C headers. Renaming it to .hpp should solve the problem.